# Python SQLite class that returns resuls as dict

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using the below function for a small project. This works but I know this is not the best way.

Any help in improving performance (or any native ways supported by Sqlite) is highly appreciated.

```
class SqliteDB(object):
    """
    SqliteDB:
    ===========================================================================
    Connects to the SQLite Database and executes provided statements.
    """
    def __init__(self, database):
        """
        Sets up environment, connects a database file.
        """
        self.parent_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(\
                os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        self.db_path = os.path.join(self.parent_directory, database)
        self.db_connection = sqlite3.connect(self.db_path)
        self.db_cursor = self.db_connection.cursor()

    def execute(self, query, args=''):
        return self.db_cursor.execute(query, args)

    def execute_dict(self, query, args=''):
        """
        execute dict
        =======================================================================
        Same as execute but returns results as a dict containing dict
        mapped with column names.
        """
        result = self.execute(query)
        column_names = []
        return_list = []
        for row in result.description:
            column_names.append(row[0])
        result = result.fetchall()
        for res in xrange(len(result)):
            temp_dict = {}
            for col in xrange(len(column_names)):
                temp_dict.update({column_names[col]:result[res][col]})
            return_list.append(temp_dict)
        dict1 = {'result':return_list}
        return dict1
```

Comment: See [How can I get dict from sqlite query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300464/how-can-i-get-dict-from-sqlite-query)

Comment: Can you provide some more information about what kind of project this is?

Comment: @SimonForsberg, I'm writing a small program which takes the input from end user (voice or text) and turns it into a query model (python dictionary) which is used to generate an SQL query statement. Now I'm looking for a better way to get the results from SQLite in dictionary format. Please let me know If I need to add more details.